# How do I get the form data in Codeigniter controller using ajax?

Tags: json, ajax, forms, codeigniter

http://zivite.com/salary/

Hi, Guys please visit the link above mentioned. 
Whenever choosing the designation from the dropdown, it will be listed all the data associated with that particular designation.

In the loop data, I have added form around the tr and submit button as well as added some additional fields like attendance, loan, rate etc. Whenever hit the submit button for a particular person. it should be stored in my database table which called the salary table.

Now my problem is not getting the data inside the model when we hit the submit button,

If you inspect it you can see array is creating there but no data from the submitted form
 see this image link below
https://ibb.co/h11SgMV

// view

```
<?php include "template/header.php"; ?><!-- Start Page content -->

    <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="card-box">
                <form action="%3C?php%20echo%20base_url('con_employee/employeeSearch');%20?%3E" class="form-inline" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group" style="padding-right:10px; width:100%;">
                        <select class="custom-select" id="empDesignation" name="empDesignation">
                            <option selected>
                                Designation
                            </option><?php foreach($categories as $category){ ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $category['cat_id']; ?>">
                                <?php echo $category['cat_name']; ?>
                            </option><?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </form><br>
                <div class="row">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-centered m-0 table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Designation</th>
                                <th>Account Number</th>
                                <th>Attendance</th>
                                <th>Rate</th>
                                <th>Loan</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="salaryData"></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- container -->
    </div><!-- content -->
    <!-- end row -->
    <script>
    $(function() {


       $('#empDesignation').change(function() {
           var user_designation = $(this).val();
           if (user_designation == '') {
               $('#empName').prop('disabled', true);
           } else {
               $('#empName').prop('disabled', false);
               $.ajax({
                   url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>con_salary/add_salary_for_employee",
                   type: "POST",
                   data: {
                       'user_designation': user_designation
                   },
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success: function(data) {

                       var html = '';
                       var i;
                       for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                           html += '<tr>' +
                               '<form class="" id="myform">' +
                               '<td>' + data[i].emp_name + ' <\/td>' +
                               '<td>' + data[i].cat_name + '<\/td>' +
                               '<td>' + data[i].emp_account_number + '<\/td>' +
                               '<td>' +
                               '<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="attendance" placeholder="Attendance" required>' +
                               '<\/td>' +
                               '<td>1<\/td>' +
                               '<td>' +
                               '<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="loan" placeholder="Loan" required>' +
                               '<\/td>' +
                               '<td>' +
                               '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary item-edit" id="btnSave">Submit<\/a>' +
                               '<\/td>' +
                               '<\/form>' +
                               '<\/tr>';
                       }
                       $('#salaryData').html(html);

                       // $('#salaryData').html(data);
                   },
                   error: function() {
                       alert('No Data');
                   }

               });

           }
       });
    });


    //insert data to salary table
       $('#salaryData').on('click', '.item-edit', function() {
           $('#myform').attr('action', '<?php echo base_url() ?>con_salary/addSalary');

           var url = $('#myform').attr('action');
           var data = $('#myform').serialize();
           var attendance = $('input[name=attendance]');
           var loan = $('input[name=loan]');    


               $.ajax({
                   type: 'ajax',
                   method: 'POST',
                   url: url,
                   data: data,
                   async: false,
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success: function(response) {

                   },
                   error: function() {

                   }
               });

       });


    </script> <?php include "template/footer.php"; ?>
```

// controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Con_salary extends CI_Controller 
{

public function __construct(){
    parent:: __construct(); 


    $this->load->model('queries_salary');       
}


public function index()
{   $data['categories'] = $this->queries_salary->fetchCategory();
    $this->load->view('employee_salary_view',$data);
}


public function add_salary_for_employee()
{
   $designation_id=$this->input->post('user_designation');
    $users = $this->queries_salary->fetchEmployeeforsalary($designation_id);

    echo json_encode($users);


}

public function addSalary()
{
    $result = $this->queries_salary->addSalary();


    // $msg['success']=false;
    // $msg['type']='add';

    // if($result){
    //     $msg['success']=true;
    // }

    // echo json_encode($msg);

}


//end
}
?>
```

// model

```
<?php 

class Queries_salary extends CI_Model
{

    public function fetchCategory()
    {
        $query= $this->db->get('category');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    public function fetchEmployeeforsalary($designation_id)
{
    $this->db->where('emp_designation_id',$designation_id);
    $this->db->join('category','employee.emp_designation_id = category.cat_id');
    $query=$this->db->get('employee');


    if($query->num_rows()>0){
        return $query->result();
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

    // $this->db->where('emp_designation_id',$designation_id);
    // $query=$this->db->get('employee');


}

public function addSalary()
{
    $field = array(
        'salary_attendance'=>$this->input->post('attendance'),
        'salary_loan'=>$this->input->post('loan')
    ); 


    print_r($field);
    exit();

    // $this->db->insert('salary',$field );
    // if($this->db->affected_rows()>0)
    // {
    //     return true;
    // }
    // else{
    //     return false;
    // }



}



//end
}?>
```

Comment: What is your request form data for when you submit the form? Is the form properly serialized there? (just go to headers in dev tools for the request and scroll all the way to the bottom if using chrome)

Answer (score 0):

A form is not allowed to be a child of a table, tbody or tr HTML elements. 
If attempting to put one there will tend to cause the browser to move the form to it appears after the table.So in your case form results an empty data.

Here i adjusted code your code little bit and will work for you.

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   html += '<tr class="user_data" >' +
       '<td>' + data[i].emp_name + ' <\/td>' +
       '<td>' + data[i].cat_name + '<\/td>' +
       '<td>' + data[i].emp_account_number + '<\/td>' +
       '<td>' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control attendance"  name="attendance" placeholder="Attendance" required>' +
       '<\/td>' +
       '<td>1<\/td>' +
       '<td>' +
       '<input type="text" class="form-control loan"  name="loan" placeholder="Loan" required>' +
       '<\/td>' +
       '<td>' +
       '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary item-edit" id="btnSave">Submit<\/a>' +
       '<\/td>' +                       
       '<\/tr>';
}
```

Bottom side script

```
$('#salaryData').on('click', '.item-edit', function() {

   var url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>con_salary/add_salary_for_employee';
   var current_row = $(this).closest('.user_data');                   
   var data = { attendance: current_row.find('.attendance').val(), loan: current_row.find('.loan').val() };

   $.ajax({
       type: 'ajax',
       method: 'POST',
       url: url,
       data: data,
       async: false,
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(response) {

       },
       error: function() {

       }
   });

});
```

One **important note** is that if you are using single form and using same type of input with same name use it as Array.

Eg : `name="loan[]"`

Comment: Thanks for you help.I have used this script, but nothing happening even action did not work. where should I put the action tag of form ? inside the script or html?. as well as not triggering the controller.